# MySql Says Column can't be null for a column that is not null! [using named parameters]

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, database

I am trying to execute an INSERT INTO query using .Net through the MySql/.NEt connector. The query makes uses of Parameters. It is rather simple:

```
INSERT INTO post (
ID, content, post_url, blogID, title, addedOn, 
updatedDate, commentsFeedURL, active, viewCount, 
commentCount, languageID, authorName, postDate, 
posRating, negRating, adult) 
VALUES(
@ID, @content, @post_url, @blogID, @title, @addedOn, 
@updatedDate, @commentsFeedURL, @active, @viewCount, 
@commentCount, @languageID, @authorName, @postDate, 
@posRating, @negRating, @adult)
```

When I run it (with all parameters duly assigned) I get an error

"Column 'post_url' cannot be null"

But it is not Null. This is the value in the parameter post_url

http://abcd.wordpress.com/2007/08/13/%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%8b-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%a8%e0%a4%9f-%e0%a4%95%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%a7%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%a8/

And this is the code I am using to assign the parameters to the SQL Query

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("post_url", postOld.URL);
```

What could be the reason that I am getting this behavior?

Comment: can you try printing out the actualy query string?

Comment: Yes, the actual query string is a part of the post. The bit that starts with 'INSERT INTO'. Try scrolling it.

Comment: also, why don't you enclose your string parameters in quotes?

Comment: oh, its mysql variables? where do you set them? are you sure it's in the same scope?

Comment: I suggest you try to "SELECT @ID, @content, @post_url, @blogID, @title, @addedOn, @updatedDate, @commentsFeedURL, @active, @viewCount, @commentCount, @languageID, @authorName, @postDate, @posRating, @negRating, @adult" and check its output. what do you see in url_post's position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay folks I finally found the right answer.

The problem was simply that in MySQL queries parameters are marked by '?' not '@'. Unfortunately many queries seemed to run fine (they weren't) using '@' so one finds this out later when there's trouble.

Thank you for all your answers. I re-wrote my query like this:

```
INSERT INTO post (ID, content, post_url, blogID, title, addedOn, updatedDate, commentsFeedURL, active, viewCount, commentCount, languageID, authorName, postDate, posRating, negRating, adult)" +
                            " VALUES(?ID, ?content, ?post_url, ?blogID, ?title, ?addedOn, ?updatedDate, ?commentsFeedURL, ?active, ?viewCount, ?commentCount, ?languageID, ?authorName, ?postDate, ?posRating, ?negRating, ?adult)
```

and it worked.

Comment: Apparently no one in the MySql world uses parameterized queries. What a waste!

Comment: Named parameters in PHP with PDO use a colon as a prefix (eg., "VALUES(:ID)"), and only unnamed parameters where available with the MySQLi extension, delimited with a question mark (eg., "VALUES(?)"), so I wouldn't have caught this error, being unfamiliar with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you call the Execute method, can you check then to see what value is in each parameter? It's very easy to accidentally do something that messes up.

Comment: Yes, I did check. It's the very same value I've provided.

Comment: Ok... perhaps temporarily allow NULL on that column and see what's being inserted then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an insert trigger on that table?  It could be that the trigger is trying to insert in to another table that has a post_url column that cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving post_url before content in the parameter and value lists to rule out the possibility that the driver passed the parameters to MySQL badly due to a complex value in @content.

Comment: I thought of that too, so then I created an SQLEncode function to correctly encode any value in content. Doesn't work.

Comment: Still, isn't it worth a try just changing the order to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not being snarky here, but this is why test cases are a good thing. Write a unit test to validate that passing a non-null posturl will work, and passing a null one will get this error form the database.

Then write an integration test (or a mock) to prove that `postOld.URL` is non-null.

Comment: Well, the postold.URL is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line look like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post_url", postOld.URL);
```

or can you omit the @ symbol?